# How to use result of a regrex for further matching?

Tags: python, regex, plsql

Say i have a regrex like this

```
[\d%]+
```

so for 4500%, it will match. Now i want this matched string be further used in regrex. How can i write such regrex. In this example, i would like to write a nested kind of regrex for the matched string 4500% that should match only numeric and trim off the %.

Comment: Please add more sample data to make your question clear.  I don't see `$` appearing anywhere in your current question, other than the pattern.

Comment: Your above regex `[\d%$]` will only match one character as it doesn't have `+` or `*` quantifier. Also, as you said you only want to match numbers, use `\d+` which will automatically ignore `%` and `$`

Comment: updated question

Comment: are you sure your tags `python` and `plsql` should be at the same time ..?

Answer (score 0):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/iBoHMd/1) creates a group that you can simply call using `$1`, which is the numeric part:

```
([0-9\.]+)%
```

[image]